# How to read through binary (.dat) file and return greatest int value python

Tags: python, binary

I am having trouble working with the integers I loop through and print out in the binary file.

I have a main program that creates a binary file, writes x amount of random integers to the file, then closes the file.

*Throughout these code snippets, I import dump and load from pickle

```
from pickle import dump
from random import randint

output_file = open('file.dat', 'wb')
    # 10 random integers
    for i in range(10):
        dump(randint(1, 100), output_file)
    output_file.close()
```

I have created a program that will open this file, unpickle each integer and print them out. However, now I also want to work with these numbers: max, min, sum, etc. When I try to produce code that (I thought) would do this, I am getting:

`33 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "binary_int_practice.py", line 13, in <module>
   for i in load(input_file):
   TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

My code is below:

```
input_file = open('file.dat', 'rb')
print("Here are the integers:")
while True:
    try:
        i = load(input_file)
        print(i, end=' ')
        big = 0
        for i in load(input_file):
            if i > big:
                big = i
        print('The max number in the file is: ', big)
    except EOFError:
        input_file.close()
        break
```

Can someone explain or help me understand where I am going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the full stack trace of your error?

Comment: see edits in question now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`load` returns the next value read from the file; in your case, each value read is an `int` (just as you wrote them).  It does *not* return an iterable that you can loop over.

So you'll have to get each number with its own call to `load`.

Comment: If you have control over the generation of the pickle .dat file, you could also adjust that to dump a list of `int`s to the file, which would then only require a single call to `load`.

Comment: Thank you for this clarification. I don't necessarily want to dump the ints into the same file I call to load in because eventually returning the integers/max/min  etc will be placed in a method to be called for any file.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use a list, fill it and add it to the file using "dump". because at each iteration the "randint" number changes in the file.

### here is the code that works well

```
from pickle import dump
from random import randint

output_file = open('file.dat', 'wb')
# 10 random integers
data = []
for i in range(10):
    data.append(randint(1, 100))
dump(data, output_file)
output_file.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Just as a clarification, if I create the binary file with my first snippet there is no way to return values,max, min from that file with another program?

Comment: you cannot because at each iteration the value changes with the new value of the new iteration. ie the file with each iteration and at the exit of the loop contains only one value (this is why it gives you this error)